# Mobile Detection without HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, mobile

Im using [Mobile detect js](https://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/#svn/ASP_NET%253Fstate%253Dclosed) to detect if the request is coming from a mobile or not.
The script is looking for the HTTP_USER_AGENT and HTTP_ACCEPT on the request for it to be able to do the detection. But in our case, there are cases that the request doesn't have this headers (eq. Bot). Needless to say, The mdetect throws error when it encouters this requests. Any idea on possible workaround on this?

```
useragent = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToUpper();
httpaccept = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].ToUpper();
```

Comment: Do you want to detect even those "devices" or just want to eliminate the error? If later, just use try/catch.